# Is Dragon Ball Super considered canon?

Tags: dragon-ball-super

Is Dragon Ball Super considered an original works by Akira Toriyama?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This really depends on [what you consider canon](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/5219/11469), but for now let's define "canon" as material that's covered in the original source material and has impact on the story.

Since this season does have a manga adaptation and takes place after [Kid Buu Saga](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Kid_Buu_Saga) from *Dragon Ball Z* but before the tournament with Uub, I would say that this **is canon** material.

---

*But*, After seeing more then the first episode I think its safe to say that the anime does not follow the manga 100%. Therefore I consider it **somewhat canon**.

Comment: Is the manga being created by Toriyama-sensei?

Comment: @krikara [he wrote the plot and the character draft](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/news/2015-04-28/dragon-ball-gets-1st-new-tv-anime-in-18-years-in-july/.87608).

Comment: This answer is wrong though. In the first chapter we see the fused Supreme Kai and Kubito, which happens only during the Fusion Saga and we also see how Goku defeated Kid buu, which happens during the Kid Saga. It seems that the story enters before the timeskip from chapter 518.

Comment: the story actually takes place after the buu saga but before battle of gods and fukkatsu no F

Comment: @jordykramer. What buu saga are you talking about? Are you talking about the Kid buu saga? I might be nitpicking here but thats actually incorrect because the kid buu saga ends with goku flying off with Uub, 10 years in the future and the Super series is obviously before that tournament. As i said, the story takes place within the kid buu saga, just before the 10 year time skip.

Comment: @PeterReaves. mhm it seems you are correct there peter, it seems the story of dragn balll super takes place after goku beat kid buu but before the tournement with uub.

Comment: Most part of the anime is not in the manga adaptation though. So according to your own definition of canon, it would not be considered canon?

Comment: @PeterRaeves well, I wrote this answer after seeing the first episode. I agree on the fact that the anime does not follow the manga 100% and that its really up to the viewer to decide. I shall edit my answer.

Comment: After a couple of years the anime and the manga have shown to be very different in some aspects.

Answer (score 6):

**Yes, it is. The stories for both the anime and manga versions of Dragon Ball Super are indeed written by Akira Toriyama**.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon_Ball_Super):

> In addition to his role as series creator, Akira Toriyama is also credited for the "original story & character design concepts" of the new anime directed by Kimitoshi Chioka.

> The anime is being adapted into a companion manga by Toriyama alongside artist Toyotarō, author behind the official Resurrection 'F' manga adaptation. It began serialization in the August 2015 issue of V Jump, which was released on June 20.

**This leaves open your title question whether the anime should be considered canon.**

[Here](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/9940/6166) Madara Uchiha answered that filler equals not canon, while pieces written by the original author should be considered canon. Now the DBS anime is both, seeing how "Vegeta's day out" would be filler, yet is written by the original author.

[Here](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/5219/6166) ton.yeung answered that something should be considered canon when the material is borrowed from the original works. So if you would consider the manga as *original work*, than the anime would be filler, yet if you would consider Toriyama's mind as *original work* it would be canon.

Seeing how at this point it is rather messed up and confusing, **my two cents would be that it will probably be considered filler (non canon) after a while**. People would either forget (or don't care) the additional episodes were produced by Toriyama or would stick by the general rule that **only** the original works (aka the manga in this case) can be considered canon, despite the author of the anime. So, not sure if it is, but **manga readers will probably consider all the extra content not to be canon**, while anime watchers will probably not even know/care about the existence of the manga and [unknowingly think everything that happened in the anime to be canon](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/19940/6166).

Comment: I think you should cite: `Written by  Akira Toriyama (Story & Character Draft)` part in the box on the right hand side, which is stronger assertion in my opinion.

Comment: @nhahtdh I have the feeling OP is asking more than just `Did he write the story` and that he does not seem to know that there is also a manga adaptation for the series. If he did, he could have just wikipedia-ed the series himself and found the author. That's why the focus was more on that, than just the author. Also I don't really see how `Written by Toriyama` or `Being adapted by Toriyama` is much different though.

Comment: I had a misconception that the OP asks about the anime exclusively, so that's the reason of my comment.

Comment: @nhahtdh I guess it boils down again to the question "What is considered canon". The anime might be written by Toriyama, but seeing how most of the anime is not even in the manga and does not really contribute to the story, should it be considered canon? :/

Comment: +_+ Dunno, it really is a mess with this series and the definition of canon also. I was intending to provide another point of view to the issue when I asked you to put your comment up as answer, but didn't realize it was such a mess.

Comment: Being written by Akira Toriyama can't be the only reason to consider Dragon Ball Super canon. Because Battle of Gods and Resurrection of F also were written by Akira Toriyama, and they have some concepts/events different to Dragon Ball Super . I have doubts if it's absolutely canon. In the future they might take ideas from those movies over Dragon Ball Super to write sequels.

Answer (score 1):

As much as i love super already... Technically Super is not cannon with Z either. Why? because it takes place straight after the buu fight (Between the 10 year time skip). Pan's not even born yet & Goku sure as hell had not activated god mode before the fight with Uub at the tournament (Last Episode Of Z). Completely parallel timeline. Although it does state it is on: http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Dragon_Ball_timeline , however it also states GT is apart of the timeline aswell which many would argue is not. But still a series worth watching and cannot wait to see how it pans out!

Comment: While the story will indeed contradict the 10 year peace of the original story, the question was more about the author of DBS. DBGT was not written by Toriyama and by that reason not considered *canon*, but DBS has been written by the same author as DB though and will by that reason be considered *canon* I suppose.

Comment: @PeterRaeves Exactly. Canon just means an original works by the author in question. There may still be plotholes in the story, like in this case.

Comment: @PeterRaeves: You might want to put the fact that the author of DBS is the original author of DB as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is.  Now here's something I didn't realize until I looked into it, if you want to get technical: DB Super, being written by Akira Toriyama, will actually be the ONLY dragon ball anime that IS canon.  I'm Not sure why people think it isn't, they are all wrong.

Dragon ball, DBZ, and GT are technically NOT canon as Toriyama didn't write for them.  They were based directly and heavily on his manga but he didn't write for those anime so they can't be considered canon per se.  He has also called GT a "side story" so while most fans consider the first two animes MOSTLY canon (due to his influence) as he wasn't really TOO involved in GT (aside from some plot points and character design) most fans don't consider GT canon.

Super will actually be the only dragon ball anime that is canon.

Comment: Do you possibly have an sources for this?

Comment: yes, simply re-read my post.  The CREATOR who wrote the original canon did NOT write these series and thus are not canon...just fan fiction.  Being a well funded fan fiction doesn’t make it canon