# Where in the Dragon Ball timeline is the Super series?

Tags: dragon-ball-super

At the end of the Dragon Ball series we can see [Goku fly off with Uub towards his village to train](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWTlM.jpg). There had been years of peace so we see Goten and Trunks all grown to teenagers, yet in the Super series they are still young. So it seems that Uub does not exist yet and the Super series does not follow directly after the Dragon Ball series, the same way the GT series did. So where does it fit in? When does the Super series take place?

Comment: I believe I heard somewhere that it takes place a few months after Buu was defeated.

Comment: I covered a bit in on this topic [here](http://anime.stackexchange.com/q/23029/11469).

Comment: I read that it is set after the defeat of Majin Boo, when the Earth has become peaceful once again. I suggest you watch Dragon Ball Z Battle of the Gods, and Revival of F

Comment: Do you have any other details as to why it's set after the defeat on Majin Boo? Specifically in regards to the points brought up in the question?

Comment: Also, you said you "read" that it is set after that? What website/magazine/etc did you read this in?

Comment: Don't forget that DBGT is NOT a part of the real timeline. It's invalid. DBZ ends (with ep 291?) as you said with that scene, therefore this happens between then. DBGT is akin to a spinoff. It not what comes after DBZ. Similarly, almost none of the DBZ movies are part of the real timeline. Specifically DBZ Movies 1-13 are not, though Bardock and Trunks story are.

Answer (score 5):

In the last episodes of *Dragon Ball Z*, the Tenkaichi Tournament takes place 10 years after Buu's defeat.

Pan is one of the tournament participants, at the age of 4.
Goten and Trunks are teenagers.

In *Dragon Ball Super*, Pan is still in Videl's womb.
Trunks and Goten are still kids.

You can say that Dragon Ball Super takes place before that tournament and after Buu's defeat.

Mind-blowing fact: Goku can already transform into SSG in that same tournament eheheh :D

EDIT: Here's the timeline from the [Wikia](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Dragon_Ball_timeline):

> **Dragon Ball Super**
>    **Age 778**
>    Around August 18 Beerus awakens from a
>   slumber and searches the Super Saiyan God.
>    Bulma's birthday party is
>   held on a cruise ship.
>
> **Dragon Ball Z**
>   **Age 781, May 7** 
>   The 27th World Martial Arts Tournament takes place. Mr.
>   Satan wins. Buu comes in second place.

Comment: Lol @ attempting to construct an answer that relies on canon continuity.

Comment: @SamIam. The canon is continuous, no?

Comment: @VISQL uh... yeah.  That's why it's laughable to construct an answer based on canon continuity.

Comment: Apart from the fact that Pan participated in the 28th tournament as opposed to the 27th, it makes sense. So it takes place 4 years after Buu was defeated and 6 years before the 28th tournament in which Uub participated.

Comment: What I meant is that the canon IS continuous.